# Django-Postman /messages/ only loads my base.html

Tags: python, django

I have

`url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman', app_name='postman')),` in my `urls.py` and

`'postman',` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`

but when I go to `127.0.0.1:8000/messages/inbox` all I can see is my `base.html` contents. This is also the case when I `View Page Source`.

The only change I have made to the `postman` directory is the first line of the file: `postman/base.html`:

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}{# CHANGED THIS LINE #}
{% load i18n static %}{% load postman_tags %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Messaging" %}{% endblock %}
{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'postman/css/postman.css' %}" />
{% endblock %}
{% block postman_menu %}
<ul id="postman_menu">{% postman_unread as unread_count %}
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:inbox' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Inbox" %}{% if unread_count %} <strong>({{ unread_count }})</strong>{% endif %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:sent' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Sent Messages" %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:write' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Write" %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:archives' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Archives" %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:trash' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Trash" %}</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed a bit in the documentation requiring certain blocks to be added.

> The postman/base.html template extends a base.html site template, in
>   which some blocks are expected:
>
> title: in , at least for a part of the entire title
>   string extrahead: in , to put some  and 
>   elements content: in , to put the page contents
>   postman_menu: in , to put a navigation menu